# Calling Macros in C [HIWARE compiler for M68K Freescale]

Tags: c, compiler-construction, macros, compiler-errors

I'm trying to call some macros in my c program. Macros without arguments are OK, but I get error If I add an Argument.

for example this is what I am calling from a header file in my c program.

```
/**Retrieve the value from the persistent store for the given key **/
#define wifi_cmd_flash_ps_load(KEY) \
{\
bglib_temp_msg.cmd_flash_ps_load.key=KEY;\
bglib_temp_msg.header=(((uint32)wifi_dev_type_wifi|(((uint32)2+0)>>8)))|((((uint32)2+0)&0xff)<<8)|((uint32)0x7<<16)|((uint32)0x4<<24);\
bglib_output (4+2,(uint8*)&bglib_temp_msg,0,(uint8*)NULL);\
}


/**Uploading is finished.**/
#define wifi_cmd_dfu_flash_upload_finish() \
{\
bglib_temp_msg.header=(((uint32)wifi_dev_type_wifi|(((uint32)0+0)>>8)))|((((uint32)0+0)&0xff)<<8)|((uint32)0x0<<16)|((uint32)0x3<<24);\
bglib_output (4+0,(uint8*)&bglib_temp_msg,0,(uint8*)NULL);\
}
```

This is a error I get:

```
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1085: cmd_flash_ps_load is not a member
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1816: Unknown struct- or union-member
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1421: Undefined class/struct/union
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: k not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: bglib_temp_msg not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1421: Undefined class/struct/union
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2801: ';' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: bglib_output not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: uint8 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2450: Expected:  . * + - & ! ~ ++ -- -> [ (  IDENT CONSTANT STRING sizeof __alignof__ __va_sizeof__    
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1827: Arithmetic types expected
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: bglib_temp_msg not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1826: Integer-expression expected
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1815: uint8 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2450: Expected:  . * + - & ! ~ ++ -- -> [ (  IDENT CONSTANT STRING sizeof __alignof__ __va_sizeof__    
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1827: Arithmetic types expected
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C1844: Call-operator applied to non-function
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(496): WARNING C1420: Result of function-call is ignored
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(507): ERROR C1815: TPU_init not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(508): ERROR C1815: TPU_Buzzer not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(520): ERROR C1815: tm_init not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(526): ERROR C1815: BulkStart not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(528): ERROR C1815: tm_start not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(528): ERROR C1815: tm_create not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(528): ERROR C1815: T_Background not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(528): ERROR C1844: Call-operator applied to non-function
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(528): ERROR C1844: Call-operator applied to non-function
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(530): ERROR C1815: tm_startup not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(543): ERROR C1815: bglib_output not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(543): ERROR C1815: on_message_send not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C1815: bglib_temp_msg not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C1421: Undefined class/struct/union
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C2801: ';' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C2801: ')' missing
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): ERROR C1815: uint32 not declared (or typename)
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(548): WARNING C1420: Result of function-call is ignored
D:\_Prj_1000\Prj_1000.c(549): WARNING C1420: Result of function-call is ignored
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `cmd_flash_ps_load != wifi_cmd_flash_ps_load`.

Comment: Please add the code where you are using the macro. Looks like `bglib_temp_msg` is not defined at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
bglib_temp_msg.cmd_flash_ps_load.key=KEY;\
```

you do not appear to have defined `bglib_temp_msg` as struct. It is not clear whether that is meant to be done in the body of the function calling it (i.e. whether the caller is meant to have a local variable of that name) or whether, as I suspect, you want something like:

```
struct mystructuretype bglib_temp_msg;
```

first (obviously with the correct structure name). Remember to `#include` or precede the use by the relevant structure declaration.